# SearchView is not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

i am trying to implement a searchView function in fragment. The searchView is in a custom action bar this is the code i used but it is not working. If i move the searchview to the fragment layout it works, but it doesnt work in action bar.

```
public class TabActivity_adbya extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    GridView gridView;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabaseInstance;
    private DatabaseReference booksInstance;
    SearchView sv;

    AlbumDBHandler db;
    ArrayList<mokdmatData> books = new ArrayList<>();
    maKotabAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancestate) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_adbya,container,false);

        ((makalat2) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ((makalat2) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
        ((makalat2) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        textViewTitle.setText("Articles");


        sv = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.svZelal);
        sv.setQueryHint("Search...");

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return true;
            }
        });


        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView_adbya);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        db = new AlbumDBHandler(getActivity());
        getData();
        init();

        return rootView;
    }
```

This is the custom action bar i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
       >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            />
    <com.mediamer.metwally.saidkotb.helpers.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            />

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/svZelal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:searchIcon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see menu file which you are using for `svZelal` (SearchView).

Comment: i think you need to declare its fucntionality in fragment again.setHasMenuOptions(true) and implement onCreateOptions and click handling methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use searchView as menu item, then you need to add menu in you fragment by using below code:

```
private MenuItem mSearchItem;
private SearchView sv;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}    


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu); // Put your search menu in "menu_search" menu file.
    mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.svZelal);
    sv = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchItem);
    sv.setIconified(true);

   SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
   sv.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
   sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            mSearchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
          adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
    });
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

I hope its helps you.

Comment: what's mSearchView in this example?

Comment: It is code typo. I have just updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to bind SearchView in MainActivity and declare `public static SearchView searchView;` and then use in fragment like `MainActivity.searchView.setQueryHint("hint");`

Comment: the search view is in action bar